# Ubuntu 18.10 -- Intel Microphone Array Not Working

Tags: 18.10, microphone, hda-intel

My microphone doesn't work in Ubuntu. I have no idea why. I've tried ALSA and pavucontrol to fix it but no luck. My sound card is HDA Intel PCA.

[image: Pavucontrol]

[image: alsamixer]

Comment: Output of `pactl list sources`? Also, do you know it works on another OS so you are confident it's not a hardware issue?

Comment: I see that You have `auto-mute` enabled. Can You disable it and see if that helps ?

Answer (score 1):

I've had reverse problem. I have a Leadtek Winfast 2000XP Expert TV/FM card (it's analog card); because TV standard in my country is PAL, but Ubuntu boots with the default (?) as NTSC standard - it's unpleasant audio sounds on boot. After the boot I've to run tvtime or Smplayer/Mplayer with tv:// to set the TV Standard to PAL .AND. to save my ears.

So, in `~/bin/` I have two files.

First is `02--Unmute_AUX.sh` with the relevant command written like this: `amixer -q -c 0 sset Aux unmute`.

Second is `03--Mute_AUX.sh` with `amixer -q -c 0 sset Aux mute`.

The `amixer` command is part of the alsa-utils package - as I am using 14.04 I'm not sure if this is true for newer Ubuntu versions.

I have to remember myself, when i'm rebooting/shutting down to issue the mute command, so that normal shutdown with saving alsa state will be with muted sound on AUX channel. Contrary, after I'm booted to XFCE and want to watch TV, I nust unmute the AUX line from Terminal. Currently I cannot remember how I found out that for alsa the right channel for my TV card sound is AUX - but I do know that TV card is connected with sound cable on the motherboard AUX input.